# Sweetalert2 allowOutsideClick not working on toast mode and close button not appearing on right side

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm using Sweetalert2 from https://sweetalert2.github.io/, this is my configuration

```
  swal({
      title: 'Success!',
      type: 'success',
      toast: true,
      html: response.message,
      showCloseButton: true,
      showCancelButton: true,
      allowEscapeKey: true,
      allowOutsideClick: true,
      //focusConfirm: false,
      confirmButtonText: 'Continue Shopping',
      confirmButtonAriaLabel: 'Continue Shopping',
      cancelButtonText: '<a href="' + cartLink + '" style="color:white;">View Cart and Checkout</a>',
      cancelButtonColor: '#ff6d02',
      cancelButtonAriaLabel: 'Cart',
  });
```

This is the result

[image: swal]

So, the problem is that the outsideclick true config doesn't work and the close button is not on the right. How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the author of SweetAlert2, thanks for posting this question.

#### 1. Close button

> close button is not on the right

This is fixed in the latest release (`v7.26.4`), please update your dependency.

#### 2. `allowOutsideClick` parameter

The `allowOutsideClick` parameter isn't compatible with toasts, since toasts are [modeless](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w2h2y4y.aspx) and don't have a backdrop. In the latest version you will get the console warning about incompatible with toasts parameters:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and for this great plugin. I updated the dependencies as advised and the close button is now on the normal place.